# How to access a file in Processing using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, directory, processing

I'm trying to run a Processing sketch within my android application.
In this sketch I need to access an `SVG` file located in my `raw` directory.
I don't know how to access that file, even if the file was located in a directory "data" just like how it works in Processing, it wouldn't work at all. Check this sample code:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PShape;
import processing.core.PVector;

public class Menu extends PApplet {
    /**************************************************/
    //icon:
    PShape icon;

    /**************************************************/
    public void settings()
    {
        size(displayHeight, displayHeight);
    }
    /**************************************************/
    public void setup()
    {
        icon =  loadShape("menu.svg");  //here is where an error occurs;
    }
    /**************************************************/
    public void draw()
    {
        background(0);
    }
    /**************************************************/
```

**UPDATE**

Error message:

```
                                                                --------- 

beginning of crash
09-07 07:36:07.503 2939-2986/letalis.safr.com.letalis E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Animation Thread
                                                                        Process: letalis.safr.com.letalis, PID: 2939
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String processing.data.XML.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at processing.core.PShapeSVG.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at processing.core.PShapeSVG.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at processing.core.PGraphicsAndroid2D.loadShape(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at processing.core.PApplet.loadShape(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at letalis.safr.com.letalis.Esquech_Menu.setup(Esquech_Menu.java:111)
                                                                            at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at processing.core.PSurfaceNone.callDraw(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at processing.core.PSurfaceNone$AnimationThread.run(Unknown Source)
09-07 07:36:07.578 2939-2952/letalis.safr.com.letalis W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-07 07:36:07.578 2939-2952/letalis.safr.com.letalis W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xacb7f860, error=EGL_SUCCESS
09-07 07:36:07.592 2939-2952/letalis.safr.com.letalis E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaebf1150
09-07 07:36:07.734 2939-2952/letalis.safr.com.letalis W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-07 07:36:07.735 2939-2952/letalis.safr.com.letalis W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xab2c9da0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
09-07 07:36:07.942 2939-2952/letalis.safr.com.letalis V/RenderScript: 0xa21fe000 Launching thread(s), CPUs 2
09-07 07:36:08.053 2939-2952/letalis.safr.com.letalis E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaebf1230
```

Comment: I also put stars as code separators. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks, is good to know :)

Comment: @Zardoz could you paste the error message

Comment: Ready (message error update).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading the shape may not be the issue. You're not drawing the SVG shape to the screen. menu.svg should be at the root of your project where Menu.pde is. See the screenshot below. I show where the svg file is located.

```
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PShape;
import processing.core.PVector;

public class Menu extends PApplet {
    /**************************************************/
    //icon:
    PShape icon;

    /**************************************************/
    public void settings()
    {
        size(400, 400);
    }
    /**************************************************/
    public void setup()
    {
        icon =  loadShape("Ghostscript_Tiger.svg"); 
    }
    /**************************************************/
    public void draw()
    {
        shape(icon, 50, 50, 300, 300);  // need to draw the shape you loaded
    }
    /**************************************************/
}
```

[image]

Comment: @zardoz your menu.svg might be corrupt then. Try to download another file. I got the Ghostscript tiger off of Wikipedia. Be mindful that your browser may try to convert the svg file to png. I had to use wget command to download the raw file

Comment: Never thought of it. Thank you so much J.P.
The file was corrupted indeed.
Thanks user6657161 and Yigit Bireroglu.

Answer (score 0):

You can store images (or any other data) in sdcard, sqlite database or sharedpreferences. Only those files are packed in app which are required like background image.

Comment: I am not very good with this kind of operations. But now I might have a clue of what needs to be done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to import a file without using an open directory, the Processing sketch immediately looks for a folder named "Data" within the project folder. For example, if your project is saved at

C://processingSketch/

Then all files you import with your code with lines such as
icon =  loadShape("menu.svg");

or

icon =  loadShape(dataPath("menu.svg"));

will be searched for at C://processingSketch/Data and if no such Data folder exists, it won't work.

Therefore either create the Data folder at your project folder and put "menu.svg" there OR find the open directory of the file within your Android system and include it in the code.

Comment: I tried creating the "Data" folder, placing the file in it and calling it from my code and still, no positive outcomes. I really don't understand this second option you are giving me, about finding the open directory, I am stuck. Thanks

Comment: @Zardoz I'm sorry, I might have been mistaken about "Data". I think its "data". But to be sure, you can click on "Sketch" and choose "Add File...". Like that it will automatically place it in the right folder. If this doesn't work either, try using "icon=loadShape(dataPath("menu.svg"));

Comment: Sorry, it causes an error. Can't I just specify the exact location of the file in my raw directory? (I don't know how to do it though). Thanks again.

Comment: It doens't matter whether is "data" or "Data", it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Zardoz I think you are not using the Processing IDE. Is it Eclipse? Then the problem might be about that and I think this post will solve it: https://processing.org/discourse/beta/num_1209991253.html

Comment: @Zardoz More help here: https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/12673/include-the-files-from-the-data-directory-in-eclipse-and-have-it-working-in-exports